# How to create custom file templates i VC++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I want to make a custom file template for .cpp and .h files in VC++ 2010 but can't figure out how to do this.

All I want to include in the files that I create is:

```
/* 
* File:   main.cpp
* Author: NoobiCake
*
* Created on 14. juli 2011, 14:57
*/

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
    return 0;
}
```

It's just like in NetBeans, when you create a new file it includes this in the file.

Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do it, is to create a macro to insert the desired text, and bind it to a key.

Comment: Is it also possible to insert the current time with macros?

Comment: i don't know, but i would be surprised if not.

Comment: It appears that VC++ Express Edition don't have user defined macros.

Comment: Ya. that really rots.  looks like no addins either.